# How to get Sqlite Data after installing UWP application?

Tags: c#, sqlite, xaml, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am developing one **Universal Windows Platform** Application.In that I am using **Sqlite** as my local Data Base. When I am side loading my application and installing it I am able to get Sqlite DB structure but not getting Data. **How can I get the sqlite data base along with data** after installing my side loaded application?

Below is the code I am using for creating Sqlite.

```
           if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "TestDB.sqlite")))
          {
            var sqlpath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, " TestDB.sqlite");
            using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqlpath))
            {
                conn.CreateTable<Test_TableName >();
            }
          }
```

As per one of the suggestion I have modified my **sqlite** file storage location like below

```
            Package currentPackage = Package.Current;

            StorageFolder AppstorageLocation = currentPackage.InstalledLocation;

            if (!File.Exists(Path.Combine(AppstorageLocation.Path, "TestDB.sqlite")))
            {
                // Creates Tables While Creating DataBase
                var sqlpath = Path.Combine(AppstorageLocation.Path, "TestDB.sqlite");

                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(new SQLitePlatformWinRT(), sqlpath))
                {
                    conn.CreateTable<Test_TableName >();
                }
          }
```

But I am getting below exception while creating the sqlite file using `Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path`

[image]

Because of using `Package.Current.InstalledLocation.Path` location I am unable to create Sqlite DB.

How can I resolve this issue.Am I need to do any other modifications?

Comment: Do you want to get the sqlite data after you side load the application? If so, you can put the sqlite in the [`Package.InstalledLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Package#Windows_ApplicationModel_Package_InstalledLocation) directory.

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT Yes you are correct. I have modified my question along with your suggestion. Could you please check my question and provide  your suggestions please...

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT I have tried by placing sqlite file in  physical location of 
Package location and as well side loaded folder still not getting sqlite file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the sqlite data base along with data after installing my side loaded application, you should be able to store the file in the [`Package.InstalledLocation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.ApplicationModel.Package#Windows_ApplicationModel_Package_InstalledLocation).

Since the installed location is read only that we should be able to copy the `TestDB.sqlite` file to the `Assets` folder in your project manually.

Make sure the sqlite file is marked as Content and to be copied to the output directory. Otherwise they won't be placed in the appxpackage and available at runtime.

On the first time launched the app, we can get the sqlite file from `Package.InstalledLocation` then we can copy it to the `LocalFolder`. We can add the data and deleted data in the `LocalFolder`.

For example:

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/TestDB.sqlite"));
Windows.Storage.StorageFolder localFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
await file.CopyAsync(localFolder);
```

Comment: I have placed sqlite file in Package.InstalledLocation and side loaded the application. And placed sqlite file in output directory also still I am unable to get sqlite data.

Comment: You have mentioned that we need to mark sqlite file as Content .Could you please explain me how can I do this ?

Comment: Select the sqlite file in **Solution Explorer** then set **Build Action** to **Content** and **Copy to Output Directory** to **Copy always** in **Properties**.